# Building Java server and I can't get my page to stop loading (using PrintWriter and Buffered Reader)

Tags: java, query-string, bufferedreader, httpserver, printstream

I'm building a Java server and everything has been working as expected until now.  I can serve up a static html page using two methods I wrote:  body and header.  Now, I am trying to write a new method called "bodywithQueryString".

**Problem:**
It *almost* works, but after the page is loaded, the loading won't stop.  It just loads and loads.  This is not happening with my static pages.

The only difference between the old method and new bodyWithQueryString() method is that in the new method I am using a buffered reader and print writer.  These are new-ish functions for me so I'm guessing I'm not doing it right.

**Here's how my new method is supposed to function:**
I want to pass my route and querystring (queryarray) to bodyWithQueryString method.  I want the method to read the file (from the route) to a byte output stream, do a replaceall on the key/value pair of the querystring while reading and, lastly, return the bytes.  The getResponse() main method would then send the html to the browser.

**Here's my code:**

```
public void getResponse() throws Exception {
  String[] routeParts = parseRoute(route); //break apart route and querystring
  File theFile = new File(routeParts[0]);
  if (theFile.canRead()) {
    out.write(header( twoHundredStatusCode, routeParts[0], contentType(routeParts[0]) ) );

    if (routeParts.length > 1) {  //there must be a querystring
      String[] queryStringArray = parseQueryString(routeParts[1]); //break apart querystring
      out.write(bodyWithQueryString(routeParts[0], queryStringArray)); //use new body method
    }
    else out.write(body(routeParts[0])); //use original body method

    out.flush();

private byte[] bodyWithQueryString(String route, String[] queryArray)
    throws Exception {

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(route));
      ByteArrayOutputStream fileOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileOut);
      String line;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) writer.println(line.replaceAll(queryArray[0]    ,queryArray[1]));    

      writer.flush();
      writer.close();
      reader.close();
      return fileOut.toByteArray();
  }
```

Comment: That code will not compile. You have edited out some code.

Comment: Thanks @Raedwald.  You were write.  I was trying to only post the relevant code in an effort not to waste other people's time.  I realize now that I didn't post enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not returning Content-Length header. This makes it hard for browser know when to stop loading the response.

Comment: Thank you!  You were dead on.  My content-length was off.  Thanks for the tip.